# Multimodule Spring boot application Flyway migration scripts

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I have a multi-module Spring boot application (for simplicity it is just moduleA and moduleB). Both modules access the same DB. Also, I use flyway to initialise the tables and populates initial data to the DB.

When I use the [naming schema of flyway](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#naming-1) I run into the problem that

`V1_0__init.sql` in moduleA clashes with `V1_0__init.sql` in moduleB.

I know that I could rename one of the files to `V1_1__init.sql` and it works. But the idea is that the modules can co-exist without knowing how the migration-scripts are named in the other module. Is this possible with flyway?

Answer (score 0):

Names cannot conflict as Flyway is creating a historical log and two files of the same name with different definitions would create a non-idempotent execution of the log.

But let's get back to the real problem...why are you writing two modules with one database? This is more problematic than the Flyway naming abuse. I can envision ways around this problem but I don't want to mention any idea when the foundation is flawed. If one module needs data from the other you need to build interfaces between them (or pull out into a third) as you are violating the modular separation of concerns. Simply put: don't do this.

Comment: The idea is to have a modular application where certain modules can easily be excluded for certain deployments. Some modules have some extra functionality which should not be shipped every time. How would you structure such a project if not in separate modules?

Comment: Split the modules, compose them through configuration at build time, orchestrate them through a configuration or permission service at runtime.